# Startup Applications with zsh and xmonad

Tags: command-line, login, startup, xmonad, zsh

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. I use zsh as my shell and xmonad as my window manager. I don't use gnome or any other desktop environment.

I'd like to declare some 'startup commands.' By this I mean, after I login and xmonad has started, I would like to run some commands that open my browser and a terminal window. I cannot access the 'Startup Applications' in the gnome menu, nor do I have a `.bash_profile` to insert these commands in. How can I declare these commands?

Answer (score 4):

sorry realised i put it n the comment:
http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Frequently_asked_question#Startup_programs try using the .xsession file

Comment: This doesn't appear to work - this seems to run before xmonad is started, not after, thus preventing the applications from running.

Comment: Can you check if it is being run? Put something like "echo 'ran' >>  ~/test.txt"  When you log in it should make a file with the word ran. and that you run xmonad after starting the programs.

Comment: @DavidY.Stephenson The update your question and post you .xsession Also zsh can source config files - http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/zshrc which calls .envrc

Comment: @namingFailed, You're right, it's not running. Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, Wouldn't this run the programs every time I open a terminal window?

Comment: Just checking...  The .xsession has the execute permission?